# How can I add the pagination-break-line under the pagination pages?

Tags: html

I'm currently working on a web page that includes pagination buttons, and I'm having trouble adding a break line with spacing below the pagination buttons. I've tried various approaches, but I couldn't achieve the desired result.

Here's the relevant code snippet I have so far:

```css
.heading {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.heading p {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.break-line {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  margin-top: 20px; /* Add margin-top for space gap */
  margin-bottom: 20px; /* Add margin-bottom for space gap */
}

.filter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start; /* Align the filter box to the left */
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.filter-box {
  background-color: #22A699;
  height: 10px; /* Adjust the height */
  width: 730px; /* Adjust the width */
  border: 2px double #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 14px; /* Add border radius */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.filter-text {
  margin-right: 10px; /* Adjust the spacing between the text and select input */
}

.select-input {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #3272AC; /* Adjust text color */
  border: 2px double #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 14px; /* Add border radius */
  cursor: pointer;
}

.product-title {
  font-family: "Meiryo UI", sans-serif; /* Use Meiryo UI font */
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold; /* Add font weight */
  color: #A9907E; /* Change text color */
}

.cheapest-price {
  font-family: "Meiryo UI", sans-serif; /* Use Meiryo UI font */
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold; /* Add font weight */
  color: #9C254D; /* Change text color */
}

.pagination {
  margin-top: 20px; /* Add margin-top for space gap */
  border: 2px double #FFFFFF; /* Add border style */
  display: inline-block; /* Display buttons in a line */
  padding: 5px; /* Adjust padding for buttons */
}

.pagination-button {
  background-color: #F1C376;
  color: #3272AC;
  border: 2px double #FFFFFF; /* Add border style */
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.pagination-button:hover {
  background-color: #22A699;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.pagination-break-line {
  margin-top: 40px; /* Add margin-top for space gap */
  margin-bottom: 40px; /* Add margin-bottom for space gap */
  border: none; /* Remove default border */
}
```

```html
<h1 class="page-title" style="font-family: 'Meiryo UI', sans-serif;color: #83764F;">口コミ・カスタマーレビュー</h1>

<div class="heading">
  <p class="left-align">すべての商品</p>
  <p>(5704)</p>
</div>

<div class="break-line"></div>

<p>レビューは使用者の私見です。必ず専門機関で相談してください。</p>
<p>投稿された商品画像は、パッケージリニューアルなどの理由によりデザインが異なる場合があります。</p>

<div class="product-title">
  <p style="font-weight: bold; color: #83764F;">ベンザック5%(benzac-ac)ベピオゲル|過酸化ベンゾイルゲル・ジェル1本60g|ニキビ治療 BK190927002</p>
</div>

<div class="cheapest-price">
  <p style="font-weight: bold; color: #9C254D;">最安値: 2,570円～</p>
</div>

<div class="filter">
  <div class="filter-box">
    <span class="filter-text">並べ替え：</span>
    <select class="select-input" id="sort" name="sort">
      <option value="most_liked" style="background-color: #F1C376; color: #3272AC;">参考になった順</option>
      <option value="recent_review" style="background-color: #F1C376; color: #3272AC;">新しい参考</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="break-line"></div>

<div class="pagination">
  <button class="pagination-button">前へ</button>
  <button class="pagination-button">1</button>
  <button class="pagination-button">2</button>
  <button class="pagination-button">3</button>
  <button class="pagination-button">4</button>
  <button class="pagination-button">次へ</button>
</div>

<div class="break-line pagination-break-line"></div>
```

I want to add a break line below the pagination buttons, with a spacing of two rows, so that it visually separates the buttons from the content below. I've tried adding a `<div class="break-line"></div>` element, but I couldn't achieve the desired spacing.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to accomplish this. Thank you!

Comment: Why not just either put a "margin-bottom" value in the style for the "pagination" class, or just specifically add a line break (<br />) after the pagination div?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  I see you have the `<div class="break-line"></div>` element before your pagination buttons, and I see that it has a line and the `20px` of top and bottom margin that the CSS class says it should have.  What are you wanting to do differently than this?